# properties file inside a jar has a relative path for xml inside same jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have a multi-module maven project., where one module refers another in its dependency.
I run install maven goal to get the dependencies.
Module B works on module A (refers it)

In module A their is a properties file (x.properties) which includes

```
file1.path=src/main/resources/abc.xml
```

This file1 property is refered from an xml via placeholder (in module A)

```
{file1.path}
```

Whenever I run module B I get an exception which says file not found. Since it resolves this relative path (file1.path) by adding a prefix of module B path. (which is obvious)

I can add another properties file and probably change the relative path to whatever works, but I cannot add absolute path.

I have referred many similar questions on this site, but I cannot use Class.getResourceAsStream() or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() since do not need file1.path in my code, instead the jar file uses it internally.

Please let me know if there is any way to solve this.

Comment: Are you running Module B from your IDE?

Comment: I want to run it from Jenkins